# How to get pens working after they've been dropped

Tags: office-supplies

So I have Pilot G2 (gel) pens that I get in the 10 packs or 20 packs from Walmart (the colored ones, so it comes with pink, green, blue, purple, orange, etc.) and sometimes I accidentally drop them and they just stopped working. It doesn't even land on the tip, it lands on its side, and it won't write properly. Im not sure what I can do about it. This has also happened to a couple of other brands of pens that I'm not sure of the name. Has anyone experienced this and has a solution for it? That would be great, thanks ~ John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the design of the pen, (according to my experience in experimenting with pens) I think of 2 solutions

1. - Take out the refill of the pen. *You might be able to see that the body(which contains ink) and the tip (bottom part) form 2 separate-able components.*
   - take out the tip component
   - keep the tip in the air pointing downward and allow some ink to slide down the barrel
   - just when you see that the ink is about to seep out of the barrel put the tip component back
2. If you have a spare (empty) G2 then take out its tip component and plug it into the problematic pen

    hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

grab the pen in your hand with the tip pointing away from you and flick it as if you were trying to shake water off it: flick flick flick. this tends to force the ink in the barrel back down to the tip and wet the ball again. Try writing with it and repeat the flick flick flick if it doesn't write.

if this doesn't work, park the pen overnight with its tip pointing down. next morning, do the flick routine and try writing again.